# Creating a tab with tabs.create and then injecting a content script, code attribute works, but file attribute doesn't?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I'm trying to inject a content script file into a newly created tab, and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I keep getting a `chrome.tabs.executeScript(...) is undefined` error in the Popup's console output. I'm not sure if it this detail would help, but I am using Vue with this project. First, I'll share the code.

Here's my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Example",
  "description": "Performs common searches based on input",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Example",
  }
}
```

And here's the main code located inside the popup Vue component's "method" attribute:

```
search: function() {
  const urls = Object.values(this.$store.state.urls);
  urls.forEach((item, index) => {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: item }, (tab) => {
        // Works!
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "console.log('Injected JS')" });
        // Doesn't work..
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "/content-script.js" });
        // Doesn't work..
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "Popup", tabId: tab.id })
    });
  });
}
```

This is the content script:

```
(function() {
    console.log("Injected JS from file!");
})();
```

And finally, background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.message === "Popup") {
        console.log("Got message from popupJS in background.");
        console.log("Tab id: " + request.tabId);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(request.tabId, { file: "/content-script.js" });
    }
});
```

So in the main code, I tried 3 different approaches:

1. executeScript with the **code** option. This one worked.
2. exectureScript with the **file** option. Didn't work
3. executeScript in the background script. Also didn't work. I was hoping this would also fix the `chrome.tabs.executeScript(...) is undefined` error, but I got that error again after the tab id printout.

I thought maybe it could be a pathing issue with content-script.js, I looked at the [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extensionTypes/#type-InjectDetails), but that didn't have much information in regards to pathing. The [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript#parameters) had more to work with:

> To work cross-browser, you can specify the path as a relative URL, starting at the extension's root, like this: "/path/to/script.js".

I placed the script in the root of the project, so it's located at **extension-project/content-script.js**, I've also tried including the project folder in the path string as well in case the forward slash at the beginning didn't specify the root, no success.

Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: did you read this link? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#programmatic

Comment: chrome.tabs.create switches the tab to the opened one, which in turn closes the popup and terminates its scripts so the second executeScript and sendMessage don't run. Move the entire urls.forEach block into the background script so the popup only does sendMessage(urls).

Answer (score 1):

actually, you need to write permissions properly in manifest.json like this:

```
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ]
```

Comment: This answer possibly could be improved by linking to official documentation that further explains this feature.